# CMOS on breadboard - Which P & N type MOSFETs to get started?

Tags: mosfet, cmos, breadboard

I would like to **implement** my own **CMOS logic** on a *breadboard*.

I have already designed a simple PCB with basic logical functionality but now I'm stuck on the **choice of N & P Type transistors** (MOSFET, not BJT).

I need the PMOS & NMOS to have the same K (1/2 * µ * Cox * (W/L)) in order to be more comfortable while calculating propagation times & other stuff.
Or at least very similar.

I'm completely lost. Lot of theory but when it comes to real life I don't know which component may fit my needs.

Thanks in advance.

---

it may be helpful to tell you that I know:

- how complementary metal-oxide-semiconductor logic works, since
  I'm studying it at University (Computer Engineering).
- this logic is used to implement complex circuits such as
  microprocessors & co.
- how to design NAND & NOR ports, and even Inverters (therefore
  AND & OR ports)
- It may be very difficult to reproduce some kind of CMOS logic on a breadboard due to lack of dedicated components which are usually very small on microprocessors (Have we reached 10nm :D ? )

Answer (score 4):

You can play around with making gates from transistors using the [CD4007](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4007ub.pdf) chip. It contains two complimentary pairs plus an inverter.

[image]

Some possible gates with one package:

[image]

The other thing that might be useful is a CD4016 quad transmission gate. With those two you could make just about anything, in theory.

In practice, it would be very tedious to make even a 4-bit ALU using such low levels of integration.

These days, most folks who are interested in making complex logic get into using FPGAs, which provide astronomical numbers of potential gates in a single package. There is a significant learning curve to use such parts.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will definetely examine that chip soon!

Comment: I second the choice of cd4007.